# Art of War bonuses - Are these map-wide?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Guild wars 2 features purchasable Guild bonuses in the Art of War category, which state

- WvW Fort +10% Magic Find
- WvW Fort +10%  Experience
- ...

Each says: For 12h, any fortification held by your guid in World versus World give allies a better "insert right bonus here".

Does this bonus applies only within the fort you are holding? Or is this granted for any allies on the map?

Bonus points: does a supply camp qualifies as a "Fort" for the bonuses?

Comment: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Influence#Art_of_War

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know you'll get these buffs if you're near a fort that got the buffs.
E.g. You're holding a fort and activates the buff, all players near your fort will receive this buff.
It gives a small advantage, to your allies, to defend the fort.

Answer (score 3):

The bonuses are located around the fort you are holding. Though, It is interesting to notice that the +5 supply bonus is kept around the battlefield if:

- You are at 0 supply
- You take supply under a +5 supply bonus
- You leave the fort influence

You will still have your 15 supplies until you used them.